# TypeScript внутренние модули

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, gulp, typescript, webpack

В компиляторе языка программирования TypeScript есть возможность генерации JavaScript с использованием "внутренних модулей", при этом на выходе получается один файл.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es3",
      "outFile": "./build/build.js",
      "rootDir": "./src/",
    }
}
```

Тем не менее, судя по популярности того же WebPack, идея не прижилась. Что послужило причиной такой ненависти к внутренним модулям TypeScript и почему их не рекомендуют использовать?

[image: Разработчики не любят внутренние модули]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каноничный TypeScript с внутренними модулями дольше компилировать при ОГРОМНОМ количестве файлов, относительно кода с внешними модулями, где можно просто удалить весь синтаксис типизации. Как следствие, он не отвечает требованиям разработки кода крупных предприятий, где пересборка всего проекта невозможна из-за временных ограничений.

[image: tsc-single-file]

Тем не менее, нужно понимать, что внутренние модули это НЕ плохо. Они просто другие. В малых проектах частного разработчика они гораздо удобнее внешних модулей. Что хорошо предприятиям - смерть частному разработчику. Если конфигурацию компилятора typescript нужно настроить один раз, то связку webpack+babel нужно постоянно поддерживать, что в сочетании с возникновением конфликтов версий между пакетами npm требует отдельных рук.

[image: babel-preset-deprecated]

На относительно не большом количестве файлов, разницы по времени компиляции не будет. Следует заметить, что сам компилятор TypeScript использует именно ВНУТРЕННИЕ модули. Поэтому, для частного разработчика будет лучше именно этот подход.

[image: typescript-compiler]

Для огромного количества JavaScript-библиотек, существуют дистрибутивы для классического подключения через тег  на самой веб-странице. В сочетании с файлами типизации из репозитория [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), можно отказаться от геморроя с npm, не потеряв статическую проверку типов.